# Regular expression for 0/1 or 1/1

Tags: regex

I need two regular expressions to check the format like 0/1, 3/7 or 1/1, 7/7.

The first regular expression should check that first digit before slash is less than the digit after slash.

The second regular expression should check that both digits before and after slash are equal.

Comment: We need your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Besides regex cannot do arithmetic comparisons.

Comment: At least provide the regex flavor. The second regex is trivial, but requires backreference support.

Comment: Regex isn't made for comparing values. (If the first capturing group contains an integer/digit less than the second capturing group, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the format and extract values by RegExp once, then make comparisons and add logical operations. JavaScript Example:

```
var str = "0/1";
var m = str.match(/^([\d]+)\/([\d]+)$/);
if (m!==null) {
    if (m[1]<m[2]) {
        /* first less than second */
    }
    else if (m[1]==m[2]) {
        /* equal */
    }
}
else {
    /* not mached */
}
```